# Ruby IF/else condensing

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement

This is a part of a Ruby script i've been working on, and want to condense this if statement somehow. How would you make this code shorter or less heavy, maybe using r3[i-=1] to automate in an iteration loop? It is pulling from an array:

```
r3=[5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0]

if over > r3[5]
  nx = r3[5]
  puts "Adds #{nx}"
elsif over >= r3[4]
  nx = r3[4]
  puts "Adds #{nx}"      
elsif over >= r3[3] #25
  nx = r3[3]
  puts "Adds #{nx}"
elsif over >= r3[2]
  nx = r3[2] * 2
  puts "Adds #{nx}"
elsif over >= r3[1] * 2 #5lbs
  nx =  r3[1] * 2
  puts "Adds #{nx}"
else
  nx = r3[0]
  puts "Adds #{nx}"
end
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to be [easily] generalizable (because of those `* 2` special cases)

Comment: Seems a bit [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)ish to me. I would start by transforming `r3` such that all cases look identical. Then it will be easy to refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try this***

```
for i in (1..5).to_a.reverse
  if(i==5 && over > r3[i]  || i!=5 && over >= r3[i] || i==0)
      nx = [1,2].include?(i) ? r3[i] * 2 : r3[i]
      puts "Adds #{nx}"
      break;
  end
end
```

Comment: idiomatically `for i in (1..5).to_a.reverse` would be better as `5.downto(1).each do |i|`

Comment: `(1..5).reverse_each { |i| #code here }` may suit as well.

Comment: This works well to start... it doesn't narrow down all the way to the smallest unit, but I can work with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% accurate. But maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
r = [5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0]
value = 30

nx = r.reverse.find { |e| e < value }
nx *= 2 if [10.0, 20.0].include? nx

puts nx
```

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure this as a `Hash` using `Range` keys like so:

```
h = {
  (20...50)=> 40.0, # r3[2] * 2
  (50...70)=> 50.0, # r3[3]
  (70..90)=> 70.0,  # r3[4]
  (90..Float::INFINITY) => 90.0 #r3[5]
}
```

And then iterate as:

```
# the ->{[5.0]} is to handle your else statement 
# where the over variable is less than 20.0
h.detect(->{[5.0]}) {|k,_v| k.cover?(over)}.pop
```

[Full Example](https://repl.it/L3g8/2)

On a side note as @DanilSperansky pointed out this line

```
elsif over >= r3[1] * 2
```

Will never be executed because it is equal to `elsif over >= r3[2]`. So I have not included this in the `Hash` above. I am certain you can figure out how to handle this.